# Node.js child process not starting after 2nd call

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to run a Java application with `child_process`, but after I call the `startServer()` function 2nd time the application doesn't run.

Here is my code:

```js
const config = require('./config.json')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

function startServer() {
    server = spawn('java',
    ['-jar', 'test.jar'],
    {
        cwd: config.serverDir,
        encoding: 'utf8'
    }
    )
    console.log('Server is running!')
}

startServer()

server.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("[Log] " + data.toString().trim())
})

server.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log('Server exitted with code:' + code)
    console.log('Restarting Server...')
    startServer()
})
```

Comment: Does the first `server.on('exit',` not get called at all... or is it called, just second `startServer()` does not behave as expected?

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek In the server.on('exit'  the console.log is working, the startServer() is gets called, but the process is not starting